# Manage Game Music At Fullscreen Ad Display Time

Tags: unity-game-engine, applovin

I have used AppLovin Ad Network to display fullscreen ads within the game.
So I want to turn off game music when fullscreen ad displayed and again turn on game music when fullscreen ad closed by the game player.

I have followed this guideline:
[Unity3d Integration](https://dash.applovin.com/docs/integration#iosUnity3dIntegration)

Here we have different listeners available:
[Ad Listeners in Unity](https://dash.applovin.com/docs/integration#iosUnityListeners)

I was getting the problem in iOS only in Android automatically game background music gets paused and played again when I closed the fullscreen ad.

Code that I have tested up to now:

```
public void ShowAppLovinInsterstitial()
{
    // Showing utilizing PreloadInterstitial and HasPreloadedInterstitial
    if (AppLovin.HasPreloadedInterstitial())
    {
        // An ad is currently available, so show the interstitial.
        AppLovin.ShowInterstitial();
#if UNITY_IOS
        SoundManager.Instance.EnableGameMusic(false);
#endif
    }
    else
    {
        // No ad is available.  Perform failover logic...
        AppLovin.PreloadInterstitial();
    }
}

void onAppLovinEventReceived(string ev)
{
    if (ev.Contains("HIDDENINTER"))
    {
        // Ad ad was closed.  Resume the game.
        // If you're using PreloadInterstitial/HasPreloadedInterstitial, make a preload call here.
#if UNITY_IOS
        SoundManager.Instance.EnableGameMusic(true);
#endif
        AppLovin.PreloadInterstitial();
    }
    else if (ev.Contains("CLOSEDFULLSCREEN"))
    {
#if UNITY_IOS
        SoundManager.Instance.EnableGameMusic(true);
#endif
    }
}
```

At present, game music gets paused after fullscreen ad displayed. On fullscreen ad, it was not again started.
Please give me some suggestion for the gameplay music turn on and off during fullscreen ads display.

Comment: have you set a listener object in your game?  without setting a listener object that is in your scene, you won't get the callbacks to the onAppLovinEventReceived method.  also, CLOSEDFULLSCREEN is a banner event, so you can remove that unless you're doing something with banners.

Comment: @josh, I have registered listener in Start method of gameobject and fullscreen ads working perfectly in game.

Comment: if you print out "ev" at the start of the onAppLovinEventReceived method do you see "HIDDENINTER" as a printed callback?  it seems like you aren't receiving that callback correctly

Comment: Yes, you are right in this, I will check and reply back to you. AppLovin support is really poor - now 2 days passed, I have generated a query in their dashboard but they didn't reply up to now.